# cordova and angular ui router : How to detect if state change was a back action

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

In one of my state's controller, I have been calling a service that uses an API to get data from the server. 
Now the problem is, the service gets called everytime the state changes. When the user goes back in history, the service gets called again. I want to prevent calling the API if the state change was due to a back action.

Is there any way to detect if the state change was due to a back action so that I could prevent the API call everytime?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the event for back button pressed ?

Comment: No. I have to know if the the current state was reached by a navigation back action. because listening to a hardware back button action would not work in an iOS device where a nav-back-button is to be used.